# Is a narrator's pronunciation a dialect? "How far" is the U.S pronunciation "stretching" so now?

Tags: pronunciation

When I was watching [**this video,**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCH1oRy1dINbMVp3UFWrKP0w)

I was shocked the female narrator is pronouncing the one of the most distinguished honor ( therefore, I think one needs to pronounce correctly ), Pulitzer, ( as should be pronounced ˈpʊlɪtsər' ( like a er of the word "letter" )), apparently, from 0:15: as "Pullitzer" or "Poulitzer".

And as I commented at comment line, it seems to me, she seems to be pronouncing "news" as "Neows" ( like cats crying ) from 1:59:

Furthermore, she seems to be pronouncing "bodyguards" as "baudyguards" from 2:22:

To a non native speaker which tries to listen to enhance the listening ability, this came to me with a bit of a sort of a "disappointment".

Can anybody help me with these some kind of "unpleasant" situations?

By just of a pure curiosity. But any answer / comment be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: As an American, it sounded to me just like the word "pull" in that video. What is "ou" supposed to represent?

Comment: To a non native speaker, it just sounded like so. Pull would be OK if you then so.

Comment: Well after listening again I can tell she didn't quite say it like the word "pull." I think she was trying to say it with the "ʌ" sound, pʌ-lit-zer. But she kind of over-pronounced it and maybe it came out like "ou".

Comment: @HiddenBabel In my personal opinion, her pronunciation is strange. She seems to be pronouncing "decade" not as "dee-cay-de" but as "da-cay-de".

Comment: @HiddenBabel And she seems to be pronouncing "bodyguards" as "boudyguards". Where does her probable "dialect" come from? If you know it? Thanks.(m_m).

Comment: @HiddenBabel Nah, sorry for repetitive comments. She is pronouncing "baudyguards". To non native speakers who try to learn English **through Good Morning America**, which is a famous show, it is quite disappointing.

Comment: As a native speaker of American English I can verify that I have heard a mixture of “Pyew”-litzer, and “Pull”-itzer all my life.  I think this is because people don’t know how the original “name sake“ Pulitzer pronounced his name.   Andrew Carnegie (CAR-negie or Car-NAY-gie) is another example from the early 20th century.

Comment: @whiskeychief hmmmmm...sad for people to forget such great heritages.